# unityroomに公開するとunityではうまく作動していた物体がすり抜けてしまいます。

Tags: c#, windows, unity3d

unityでゲームを製作しunityroomというサイトで公開しようとしたのですが、公開したunityroomのurlを開き実際にゲームをしてみると、unityではすり抜けなかった物体がすり抜けてしまうという現象が起こっています。

すり抜けている物体にはcapsule coliderとrigidbodyがアタッチされています。
以下、各種設定です。
【capsule colider】
Is Triger オフ
Material　なし
Direction　Y-Axis

【Rigidbody】
Mass　0.2
Drag　0
Angular Drag　2
use　Gravity　オン
Is Kinematic　オフ

すり抜けられている物体はブレンダーで制作したもので、mesh coliderがアタッチされています。
以下、各種設定です。
【Mesh Colider】
Convex　オフ
Is Trigger　オフ
Cooking Option　Everything
Mesh　立方体

[image: unityでうまく動作している様子]

[image: unityroomで公開した時にすり抜けている様子]

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: その質問内容だと、記述が少なすぎるのと手順が端折られているように見えます。他の人が問題を再現・調査出来るように、これらのヘルプ記事を参考に内容を追記・改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
記述が少なすぎるとのことでしたが、お恥ずかしながら他にどのような情報が必要なのかわかりません。
多少書き換えてみましたが、スクリプトもなく原因の見当もつかないので、何を書けばいいかすらわからない状況です。
お忙しいところ恐縮ですが、どのような情報を追加すればいいかご教授願えませんか？

Comment: 紹介したヘルプ記事や、同じ`unity3d`のタグが付いている質問等を参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ [Timelineでオブジェクトの位置を移動する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/86654/26370), [オブジェクトのすり抜けに対するアドバイスお願いいたします。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88048/26370), [Blender から Unity にインポートしたメッシュ(FBX)が、頂点アニメーションした際に分離してしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/85271/26370), [Unity void Start()の優先順位を変更する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88081/26370)

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にして少しでも関係のありそうな情報を追加してみました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: unityroom 側での問題な可能性もあります。動作環境は [投稿可能なUnityのバージョンは 5.4 ~ 2021.3 です。それ以外のバージョンについては動作確認を行なっておりません。](https://unityroom.com/help)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。いただいたURLの通りに検証したところ、
１．バージョン設定はあってる
２．Build and runをすると同じようにすり抜けてしまう。
ということがわかりました。

Comment: その後、いろいろ試して分かったことを記載します。
コメントくださった方ありがとうございました。

どうやら、ブレンダーで作った物体はZ軸方向からでしか、meshcolliderが反応しないようでした。
製作したモデルを回転させてから出力すると無事meshcolliderが反応いたしました。